# How to speed up file reading with Pandas with read_*(file) when I don't need all the rows and columns?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I know there are some other threads that explain how to deal with big files and Pandas, but in fact, I do not have memory problems, I just want to open a lot of Excel files to get a bunch of rows each time (sometimes even only one), and sometimes I don't even need all the columns.

I've seen in other threads people proposing the `usecols` and `nrows` but it appears that pandas still loads the entire sheet, then keeps only the selected rows and cols. To be sure, I've wrote this :

```
start = time.time()
couples2015 = pd.read_excel(fileInput)
total = time.time() - start

#Reloading file, with only some lines and cols
start = time.time()
couples2015 = pd.read_excel(fileInput,  header=4,  usecols=0,  nrows=10)
total = time.time() - start
```

and in both cases, it tooks about 55 seconds to load.

And that's only for a 50 Mo file, but I have to load & extract a lot of files, from 50 Mo up to 500 Mo (even sometimes up to 1 Gb)

Is there a way to extract some rows and cols without loading the whole files ?
If not, would creating DB with my excel files to use read_sql_table() be faster ?

Thanks !

[edit : moreover, each file has several sheets, but I often want only one or two. Even in I use sheet_name=0, it seems that it still opens and loads everysheet, as time is almost the same…]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using Excel for Windows, consider directly querying workbooks using the [Jet/ACE SQL Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) (Windows .dll files) via an ODBC connection to the installed Excel driver. Doing so, each sheet serves as a database table and typical SQL semantics (`JOIN`, `UNION`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`) is available and can be read with [`pandas.read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html).

Adjust below SQL statement with actual column, sheet, and ranges.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

strfile = "C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsx"

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={{Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}};DBQ={};'
                      .format(strfile), autocommit=True)    

strSQL = """SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 
            FROM [Sheet1$A4:C10]
         """ 

df = pd.read_sql(strSQL, conn)

conn.close()
```

---

For data without headers, consider an inline Excel query that specifies no headers and data starting on first row of specified range.

```
strSQL = """SELECT F1, F2, F3
            FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;Database=C:\Path\To\Same\Workbook.xlsx].[Sheet$A6:L10000]
            WHERE F2 = 'Some Value';
         """
```

By the way, if your last row is unknown, simply give it a very large number. The query engine selects only the used rows.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but works like a charm ! Thanks a lot ! I used select * because obviously col1, col2, col3… did not work. Do you know why ? Just to know how to use WHERE selections in this case…

Comment: Just to be more precise : my files do not have headers, usualy first rows are empty, tables starting row 4 or 5, so I don't get how to name my columns in SQL to SELECT only ones I'd like…

Comment: Yes, if data had headers, you can replace Col1, Col2, Col3 with actual names. You might be able to use F1, F2, F3, ... for headless data and use those in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But in fact, F1, F2, F3… does not work. I got that error : pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError
"Execution failed on sql 'SELECT F1 FROM [IRIS$A6:L490] ': ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][Pilote ODBC Excel] Trop peu de paramètres. 1 attendu. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')" (in english : not enough parameters, 1 expected). the 1/2/3 or more expected depends on the number of F1 F2 F3… that I use.

Comment: See update using an inline Excel query that specifies no headers and defaults to the `F#` format.