# Reading XLSB (binary) file with Pandas read_excel using pyxlsb reads empty rows for some xlsb file

Tags: python, pandas, pyxlsb

I'm trying to read binary Excel files using `read_excel` method in `pandas` with `pyxlsb` engine as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsb', engine='pyxlsb')
```

If the `xlsb` file is like [this file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0b38904ee6bb7c8350067eb17be1eeee20200517020036/27e852) (Right now, I'm sharing this file via WeTransfer, but if there is a better way to share files on StackOverflow, let me know), the returned dataframe is filled with `NaN`'s. I suspected that it might be because the file was saved with active cell pointing at the empty cells after the data originally. So I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
with open('test.xlsb', 'rb') as data:
    data.seek(0,0)
    df = pd.read_excel(data, engine='pyxlsb')
```

but it still doesn't seem to work. I also tried reading the data from byte number 0 (from the beginning), writing it into a new file, 'test_1.xlsb', and finally reading it with `pandas`, but that doesn't work.

```
with open('test.xlsb','rb') as data:
    data.seek(0,0)
    with open('test_1.xlsb','wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(data.read())
df = pd.read_excel('test_1.xlsb', engine='pyxlsb')
```

If anyone has suggestion as to what might be going on and how to resolve it, I'd greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: what do you mean returned with NaN ? if you are using Windows, I would suggest using `xlwings` which generally handles xlsb better than pyxslb

Comment: @Datanovice, I meant the resulting dataframe only has empty rows. I'll give `xlwings` a try tomorrow (I tried `pyxlsb` because that's what Pandas documentation suggested). Thank you.

Comment: Consider even a [`pyodbc` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124285/1422451) where you can query *any* Excel workbook type with SQL using `read_sql`.

Comment: @Parfait Very interesting approach to read Excel files and I'll certainly be using it when I use Windows. For this problem above, my environment is a Azure Batch instance with Linux OS. Thank you for sharing this unique (and very likely performant) way to read large Excel files, which has been a pain to do in Pandas.